# iOs Autolayout: resize nested views to fit content

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm building app that has UI like built-in message app or whats app.
[image: Part of my UI]

I use storyboard for creating layout. For this part of UI I have following constraints:

- Outer view:

  - To superview in front, top, right, bottom
  - Height
- UItextView

  - To outerview: front, top, right, bottom
  - Height

Now I'd like to add the exact same behavior like in standart message app (outer view grows up and uitextview resizes up to fit the content).

I've implemented

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{
    if (textView == self.messageTextView) {

        CGSize sizeThatShouldFitTheContent = [self.messageTextView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.messageTextView.frame.size.width, 150)];

        if (sizeThatShouldFitTheContent.height <= 30) {
            sizeThatShouldFitTheContent.height = 30;
        }

        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            self.messagePanelConstraint.constant = sizeThatShouldFitTheContent.height + 14;
            self.messageTextConstraint.constant = ceilf(sizeThatShouldFitTheContent.height);
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        }];
        [self setSendButtonState];
    }
}
```

But it that case I have "jumping" uitextview that sometimes has additional space and sometimes dont. Also as you can see there is "magical numbers" (30 is my initial uitextview height) and 14 - is space between uitextview and outer view.

So are there any ways to achieve that result easier with autolayout?